# how to create an activity based on item click and how to adapt data from which list item is clicked

Tags: android, android-activity, mobile-development

I am new to android . I need to know how to create a single acvtivity open when a list item is clicked but i need different datas depends on list item like imageview and textview should load different image and string. Is there is any way or i should create all activity example 10 activity for 10 item in the list or we can do by creating single activity and getting data depends on item click

Comment: you can have as many as activity you need but if you do this for list items then you can't assure that how many items you are going to have. so it is better that you use single activity and pass item's value to that activity by intent extra and in that activity get that intent extra by getIntent() method.

Comment: actually i dont want to pass the value. I am creating an exercise app when the exercise list item is clicked. i need to open an activity and that should contains images and data based on that exercise in list from resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the list position of exercise list in intent extra and use switch case to determine which image or text from resource you want to show.

```
switch(exerPos){
case exc1:{
img.setResource(R.drawable.ex1);
}

case exc2:{
img.setResource(R.drawable.ex2);
}
```

Comment: should i use switch case in onclick function

Comment: nope switch case will be used in oncreate() of your secondactivity when you will take the exercise position from the intent extra and set text and image drawable accordingly . Also in onItem click of your listview (In First activity) u will call second activity and pass intent extra in it.